# John Lee Problem 6-10

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

The following is John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth manifolds* Problem 6-10.

> Suppose $F:N\to M$ is a smooth map that is transverse to an embedded submanifold $X\subset M$, and let $W = F^{-1}(X)$. For each $p\in W$, show that $T_pW = (dF_p)^{-1}(T_{F(p)}X)$.

My attempt: Let $\dim M = m,\dim X = k$. As $X$ is an embedded submanifold, each point in $X$ has a neighborhood $U\subset M$ such that $X\cap U$ is a regular level set of local defining map $\Phi:U\to\Bbb R^{m-k}$. So for each $p\in F^{-1}(X\cap U)$, $\ker d\Phi_{F(p)} = T_{F(p)}X$. Since $F$ is transverse to $X$, $dF_p(T_pN)+T_{F(p)}X = T_{F(p)}M$. Since $W$ is an embedded submanifold of $N$, $\color{red}{\Phi\circ F:F^{-1}(U)\to\Bbb R^{m-k}\ \text{is a local defining map of}\ W.}$ Now for each $p\in F^{-1}(X\cap U)$, $T_pW = \ker(d\Phi_{F(p)}\circ dF_p)$, $v\in T_pW\iff dF_p(v)\in\ker d\Phi_{F(p)} = T_{F(p)}X\iff v\in (dF_p)^{-1}(T_{F(p)}X)$. Hence, $T_pW = (dF_p)^{-1}(T_{F(p)}X)$.

I'm not sure the highlighted red part is true since $F$ is just a smooth map. Does transversality ensure this?

Comment: You need to show that transversality is equivalent to the statement that $0$ is a regular value of $\Phi\circ F$ if $0$ is a regular value of $F$. This is the key point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand what you mean by $0$ is a regular value of $F$. Codomain of $F$ is $M$.

Comment: Oh, stupid typo. I meant $\Phi$, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. I posted my answer.

Comment: I can see that the kernels contain $T_{F(p)} X$ and $T_p W$ but how do we know that they are equal to the kernels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $0$ is a regular value of $\Phi$ such that $\Phi^{-1}(0) = X\cap U$.
Let $p\in (\Phi\circ F)^{-1}(0)\subset F^{-1}(U)$. Then we get
\begin{align*}
T_pN\xrightarrow{dF_p}T_{F(p)}M = dF_p(T_pN)+T_{F(p)}X\xrightarrow{d\Phi_{F(p)}}T_{\Phi\circ F(p)}\Bbb R^{m-k}.
\end{align*}
where the equality follows from the fact that $F$ is transverse to $X$. Since $T_{F(p)}X$ is in the kernel of $d\Phi_{F(p)}$, $d(\Phi\circ F)_p:T_pN\to T_{\Phi\circ F(p)}\Bbb R^{m-k}$ is a surjective. Hence, $0$ is a regular value of $\Phi\circ F$ and \begin{align*}(\Phi\circ F)^{-1}(0) = F^{-1}\circ\Phi^{-1}(0) = F^{-1}(X\cap U) = F^{-1}(X)\cap F^{-1}(U) = W\cap F^{-1}(U).\end{align*}
Hence, $\Phi\circ F:F^{-1}(U)\to\Bbb R^{m-k}$ is a local defining function of $W$.

Comment: It is sometimes useful to note that transversality is equivalent to the statement that $dF_p$ maps $T_pN$ surjectively to the normal space $N_{F(p)}X = T_{F(p)}Y/T_{F(p)}X$. This translates into a nice statement about normal bundles (Lee's choice of letters makes this discussion awkward). :P

Comment: Why is $d(\Phi \circ F)_p$ surjective since $T_{F(p)}X$ is in the kernel of $d\Phi_{F(p)}$?